# Pytest compare several class instances using fixtures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm learning pytest and I'm trying to generate several class instances using fixtures and compare the result of a method with a value.

For example, I have the following code. In this case I have a class called building that has a method to calculate the angle of the roof. I'm generating two instances of the class but I want to compare the angle with two differents values. At the moment I'm comparing with a fixed value (12).

How can I set the values corresponding to each instance to compare?

```
import pytest

from pywind.geometry import Building

params = [(60, 30, 6, 16, 0, 'gable'), (30, 50, 7, 13, 0, 'shed')] # Arguments

@pytest.fixture(params=params)
def building(request):
    building = Building(*request.param)
    return building

def test_roof_angle(building):
    assert building.roof_angle() == 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your fixture to provide not only a tested instance, but also a bunch of expected values to compare against in the test. Remember that you can pass as many params as you need to; however, it's up to you to organize them in a readable manner. For example, you could introduce some intermediary container holding both the building instance and the expected angle:

```
from collections import namedtuple


BuildingData = namedtuple('BuildingData', ('instance', 'expected_angle', ))


params = [(60, 30, 6, 16, 0, 'gable', 12),
          (30, 50, 7, 13, 0, 'shed', 42)]


@pytest.fixture(params=params)
def building(request):
    # all params except the last one are constructor args
    instance_args = request.param[:-1]
    instance = Building(*instance_args)
    # last param is the expected roof angle
    expected_angle = request.param[-1]
    return BuildingData(instance, expected_angle)


def test_roof_angle(building):
    assert building.instance.roof_angle() == building.expected_angle
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I will accept this answer. However, I will review my test based on the @drootang answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying do goes contrary to the concept of a fixture. From the [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) docs, the first sentence on the fixture page:

> The purpose of test fixtures is to provide a **fixed baseline** upon which tests can reliably and repeatedly execute.

I added the emphasis on fixed baseline. Here you have *two* baselines: gable and shed. To conform to the concept of a fixture, you should consider splitting gable and shed into separate fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[60, 30, 6, 16, 0, 'gable'])
def gable(request):
    building = Building(*request.param)
    return building

@pytest.fixture(params=[30, 50, 7, 13, 0, 'shed'])
def shed(request):
    building = Building(*request.param)
    return building
```

then create tests with appropriate assertions for each:

```
def test_roof_angle_1(gable):
    assert building.roof_angle() == 12

def test_roof_angle_2(shed):
    assert building.roof_angle() == 23
```

Supplying multiple argument lists to the params argument is useful when multiple fixtures should be run for the same exact test. In the example from the [pytest fixture docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) they test an SMTP response that should be identical from different URLs.

An analogy in your case would be if you had different building types that should all have the same characteristics (i.e., they all had the same roof angle), then it would be useful and appropriate to use multiple parameters to auto-run tests on multiple fixtures. Instead of using the generic "building" fixture, you could instead name it buildings_with_12roof, perhaps.

Comment: I understand. In that case I have to make several functions for differents cases if I want to make multiples instances of a "shed" building to test if a exception is raised, or other types of tests.

Comment: Should me more appropriate use `pytest.mark.parametrize` in my case?